# Pandas memory error for large dataframe pivot

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I am tring to perform a .pivot(index=x,columns=y,values=z).fillna(0) on a large pandas dataframe (25.000.000 rows).

The expected pivot output should be of 1.500.000 x 100.000 size.

The issue i'm facing is that since pandas load dataframe in memory, for such a big df I do not have enough memory and it results in MemoryError.

I see that it is suggested to perform operations in chunks, but in this case (constructing pivot table), I do not think it is feasible ?

Is there any alternative I could use (maybe write on disk, use another lib to perform) to perform this operation ?

Comment: Do you use `pivot` or `pivot_table`? `pivot` does not require any operations on data (you can use `set_index` and `unstack`). `pivot_table` apply some operations on data because you have duplicated values.

Comment: @Corralien i use `pivot`

Comment: Did you try with `set_index` and `unstack`? `df.set_index(['x', 'y']).unstack('y')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_index` and `unstack` instead of `pivot`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': list('ABCABCABC'),
                       'y': list('XXXYYYZZZ'),
                       'z': range(1, 10)})
   x  y  z
0  A  X  1
1  B  X  2
2  C  X  3
3  A  Y  4
4  B  Y  5
5  C  Y  6
6  A  Z  7
7  B  Z  8
8  C  Z  9
```

Using `pivot`

```
>>> df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z')
y  X  Y  Z
x         
A  1  4  7
B  2  5  8
C  3  6  9
```

Using `set_index`/`unstack`:

```
>>> df.set_index(['x', 'y'])['z'].unstack('y')
y  X  Y  Z
x         
A  1  4  7
B  2  5  8
C  3  6  9
```

Comment: It has better performance, but still not enough memory with this approach